# Workflow Fails to Compile and Publish in SharePoint Designer 2010

Tags: sharepoint, workflow, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

The SharePoint install is a SP2010 install on a 2008 R2 server. Everything is fully patched. I am running the SP Designer on the SharePoint Server directly.

I have a workflow which is intended to send an email when a new document is created in a custom list. I have deliberately kept the workflow very simple in order to illustrate this problem.

After creating this single step workflow in SP Designer, I click "Check for Errors" and SP Designer reports "The workflow contains no errors".

I then click "Publish" but the Workflow Error dialog is displayed with the message

> Errors were found when compiling the workflow. The workflow files
>   were saved but cannot be run.

Clicking the advanced button reveals more information:

> Could not publish the workflow because the workflow configuration file
>   contains errors

Any suggestions gratefully received

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing a clean install of the OS and SharePoint, workflows are working flawlessly. I can only conclude that the problems were caused by left over registry settings from MOSS 2007. Thanks for the suggestions that people made.

Answer (score 1):

I'll share what fixed it for me - deactivating all workflow features at the site collection level (that is, Workflows, Three-state workflow, Publishing Approval Workflow) and then reactivating the features. I was then able to publish my workflow. [This post helped](http://www.tech-services.ca/2012/03/sharepoint-online-workflow-error-user-cannot-be-found), not sure whether this only works for 365 though, but it's sure worth trying first if you are considering a reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

after googling for quite some time, i think it's an authentication issue. How is your SharePoint set up? Do you use HTTPS for authentication? If so check out [this](http://bloodinthepixels.com/?p=177) article.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I had seen the article you referred to but I am not authenticating over HTTPS so I had not tried this. I have now tried clearing the cache but this didn't help. Given that I cannot find anyone else with this problem and that the server previously hosted a MOSS 2007 I am going to re-pave the server completely and try with a clean install.

Answer (score 0):

I know this error message from sharepoint. I got this by dealing with multiple lookup fields refering to other lists. Even when I check the worfklow for errors SharePoint says that its all fine but i can't publish it at all.

Try to build a new Test-Site on your Site Collection. Build a Custom Document Library, leave it standard and then set up a new simple workflow just sending a mail.

Fill out the needed fields in mail only using simple values. Send to your mailadress, simple mail subject and simple mail body.

Set the workflow to run only manually.

Try to publish the workflow.

When this is working, then compair to your existing workflow and change your values by trail and error.

Answer (score 0):

This could also happens if you chage the URL of the web application, all you have do is click the Design button from the library itself.
when changinf the URL from `http://server/Site` to example: `http://server.xx1.net/site`, and you try to publish it tries the old url.

Answer (score 0):

what helped in my situation is changing from start workflow automatically to manually.some times answers for critical situation is very easy. hope it helps, many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem and after digging for days and folks suggesting to rebuild the servers, disabling and re-enabling site features, remove previous workflow versions, etc. and trying everything except rebuilding the servers (not practical for clients production environment). I decided to try some tests and found that this issue was only happening on one particular list no matter how simple or complex the workflow was... And when I would check the box for start automatically on item create (or when item changed) it would fail to publish and give the error above, but if I published it with just manually start worked fine. Finally after deleting views and some more testing, I discovered that there was over 240+ columns in this list (I did not create it...) and 50+ workflows set to run on create... Thankfully I have a test environment I built out for the client so I sync'd the Site Collection database back to test environment from Production re-ran my tests and got same error... So what resolved the problem and what was the ultimate cause of the problem, there was to many columns defined in the list and I had to delete several columns to publish the workflow in the test environment. This actually issue translates into the there is a limit in SQL Server on how much data the list can store each type of column takes up so much space read more about it here:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787(v=office.15).aspx#Column

So what I did in production was worked with my client to determine how to break up the list into multiple lists and have relationships between them, thus moving some of the columns and data to another list (Think database/list normalization)... I hope this solution helps someone.